# Magento password link expired

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, password-recovery

I recently updated my Magento environment to 1.9.2.3 and at first I noticed that when I tried to reset my password and clicked on the link in the email it directed me to a blank page. I fixed that now, but when I fill in the form now I get the error:

```
Your password reset link has expired.
```

How do I fix this? My customer.xml is the same as the base version of a just downloaded 1.9.2.3

Comment: check that do you have form key on login page???

Comment: do you get that message when you request a new reset too?

Comment: I do have a form key on my login page and I always get the message, so for new requests as well.

Answer (score 2):

Without looking into code or available configuration options, I can think of:

- time on insert is wrong
- time on check is wrong
- timeframe to check for is too small or even negative

After looking into the code it is kind of worse:

```
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    $this->_getSession()->addError( $this->_getHelper('customer')->__('Your password reset link has expired.'));
    $this->_redirect('*/*/forgotpassword');
}
```

This error is the fallback for "something went wrong", therefore I would hack `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php:759`, add a `Mage::logException($e)` and inspect that in the log.